# $k$-isogenies and $k$-subgroups of abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $k$ be a field of char0, with algebraic closure $\bar{k}$. Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $k$ of positive dimension and let $d\geq 1$ be an integer.

Let $S(A,k,d)$ be the set of abelian varieties $B$ over $k$ such that there exists a $k$-isogeny $A\to B$ of degree at most $d$.

Consider: (a) If $B\in S(A,k,d)$ then there exists a $k$-isogeny $\varphi_B:A\to B$ such that $\ker(\varphi_B)(\bar{k})$ is a subgroup of $A(\bar{k})$, defined over $k$, of order at most $d$.

(b) Furthermore, if $B,B'\in S(A,k,d)$ with $\ker(\varphi_B)(\bar{k})=\ker(\varphi_{B'})(\bar{k})$ as subgroups of $A(\bar{k})$ then $B$ is $k$-isomorphic to $B'$.

Note (a) holds always, and one can prove that (b) holds for $k=\bar{k}$.

1. Does (b) hold for all $k$ as above?
2. Moreover, can one use (a) and (b) to describe the set $S(A,k,d)$, up to $k$-isomorphisms, in terms of subgroups of $A(\bar{k})$, defined over $k$, of order at most $d$?

Comment: The image of your map is the the set of Galois invariant subgroups.

Comment: Since the Galois invariant subgroups are the ones defined over $k$, that should be fine.

Comment: The asserted bijection when $k = \overline{k}$ is not a bijection since two such $B$'s might be isomorphic in a manner not respecting given quotient maps from $A$.  In particular, it can certainly happen that distinct such finite $k$-subgroups of $A$ yield quotients that are isomorphic.  This question is more subtle than you seem to think, but maybe if you explain the motivation for asking it we may see that you meant to define one or both of these sets in another way (or maybe for what you care about it is not necessary to work over $\overline{k}$ at all).

Comment: I should have also said that even the map $\varphi \mapsto \ker(\varphi)$ is not well-defined, in that the isomorphism class of $B$ does not determine $\varphi$ up to a $k$-automorphism of $B$ in general.  So the formulation of the question needs to be revised.

Comment: You should define $S(A,k,d)$ be the set of isomorphism classes of isogenies $A\to B$ of degree at most $d$, and $G(A,k,d)$ to be the set of subgroups of $A(\bar{k})$ of order at most d stable under Galois. Then the statement is obvious.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @Marguax you are right, I hope the question makes now more sense?